# failing to get IPv6 remotely

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I am trying to fetch IPs of remote machine. But my code fails to collect IPv6 remotely. The code runs fine when run locally. Following is my sample code

```
System.Net.IPHostEntry hostEntryComputer;
try
{
    hostEntryComputer = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(computerName);
    foreach (System.Net.IPAddress addr in hostEntryComputer.AddressList)
    {
        string temp = addr.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("IP: " + temp);
    }               
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it  throw an exception, or is the desired IP simply not in the list? And what kind of computerName are you using? A real domain, or a network local computer name?

Comment: Your code works for me (I can get the IPV4 and IPV6 addresses from my provider). You do need a complete IPV6 chain to the other side of course.

Comment: It doesn't throw any exception, but it doesn't return IPv6, just returns IPv4. When I run the utility locally, it returns IPv6.

Comment: Did you try to provide it with remote computer name? or is it local computer where you are running this code?

Comment: Yes, the remote computer was the website of my provider. I know I have an V6 connection to there. But a random site (cnn.com) only gives V4 addresses. So it's about your subscription and the other side.

Comment: @Henk Holterman  how can I test that? I have both my machine right here with me.

Comment: @Henk Holterman note: both r vms.

Comment: I don't read txt-speek very well.

Comment: Same problem with my code

Answer (score 1):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx): "IPv6 addresses are filtered from the results of the GetHostEntry method if the local computer does not have IPv6 installed. As a result, it is possible to get back an empty IPHostEntry instance if only IPv6 results where available for the hostNameOrAddress.parameter."

Follow those tutorials to enable it on your local machine:

- [Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2478747)
- [Windows Vista/7](http://www.yellowhead.com/IPv6_How.htm)

Comment: I do have IPv6 installed on both machines (from where I am running the code and the computer from which I am trying to fetch)

Comment: both my machines ares windows 2k8r2 and IPv6 is enabled in both of them

Comment: Is IPV6 configured on the (virtual) router?